# Meaning of "intriguing" in the following sentence

Tags: adjectives, meaning-in-context, present-participles

> Reading comprehension is one of the most important parts of any management entrance examination and a bit **intriguing** as well.

Does it mean:

- Challenging?
- Interesting?
- Provocative?

All these are meanings of *intriguing* at [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intriguing) and all these fit well into the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say *challenging and interesting*

Your source says

**intriguing** : arousing great interest or curiosity

so "a bit intriguing" would lessen that.